# Maven Jetty plugin with endorsed external directory

Tags: maven, jetty, endorsed

I have a project with more than an hundred external library dependencies, here we use tomcat with this endorsed jar libs configured on a directory in the server (now is under $CATALINA_HOME/lib/endorsed), so the webapp can access those resources on runtime start.

I wanted to try jetty instead, because tomcat takes too much memory and crashes frequently. Now I'm wondering if there is a parameter to pass on maven-jetty-plugin to specify this jar's folder so as the webapp class loader find them in its classpath.

I've tried extraClasspath in configuration tag, but it seems to load only classes and ignore all jars in the directory I set into (if I pass the full name path of the jar, it is loaded, but I don't want to set every library that I need there).

Thanks in advance for the help

**update**:I know it's not a standard maven operation, i'm searching for an emergency workaround since this project is very huge and I can't refactor as I want.
But also I expected this feature was not as tricky as it seemed to me at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass them as absolute paths, or, alternatively, have them as dependencies of the plugin itself.

What you want to have done goes against Maven's portability principles, so don't expect it to support it.